# make an image size to be certain percent from the screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

In constraint layout if I want the image to be in the center horizontally and at the top of the screen, then I can do this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/image"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I make the image width and height to be 25% of the screen width and height? Is this doable?

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update:**

with new [ConstrainLayout 1.1.0](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/05/constraintlayout-110-beta-1-release.html) it's been implemented a much nicer way to do this!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff0000"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".25"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"

        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".25"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Or

You can place Guidelines with percentage and then constraint the ImageView to them. <s>It would be nice to have a cleaner way to do it but I think it's still much better than nested LinearLayout with weights</s>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline_left"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline_right"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline_top"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline_bottom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff0000"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline_left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline_right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.66"/>


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline_top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline_bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.66"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Oh thats soo cool. Finally they have the percentage but is this in the support library ??

Comment: It is cool indeed, I think I'm finally gonna say goodbye to LinearLayout. It's in the 1.1.0 version that now is in beta, you can use it very easily though, [read here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/05/constraintlayout-110-beta-1-release.html)

Comment: Yea same here. I think no need for any other layout now if we have percentages and this way we can just support multiple screens more easily. I clicked on the link, there is no info about usage beside the 2 lines.. So when it is in beta, can we use it in apps on devices running 4.1

Comment: of course you can, it's still the same support library, it's just a new version that is still beta. the usage is the same

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but isn't it kind of weird that it is still so tricky to pull off such basic thing like percentage width? Android is one of the largest platforms, it has been around for 10 years now..

Comment: app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".25" & app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent" are what i'm looking for thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can set it programmatically like this:-

```
ImageView image_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
calulate(image_view);



private void calulate(View v) 
{
    int imgWidth = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int imgHeight = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (0.25*imgHeight);
    v.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (0.25*imgWidth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With every view, android provide an override method(onMeasure) in which there are 2 parameters`(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)`, You can return height width according to your requirement. 
Example: If you want height = width means a square size view you can return height and width like this:

```
@Overrideprotected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

You can create your custom view for this :
Example: 
Make a class names CustomImageView extends with ImageView

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView
{

    @Override    
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        // you can set this as per percentage also. For example: 
        //"heightMeasureSpec * 50 /100"  ---- the height will be 50% of the 
        //view's width. 
    }

}
```

Use this in your layout like this :

```
<CustomImageView    
    android:id="@+id/imageView"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"    
/>
```